# output of cat command in newline for every sentense

Tags: linux

I am using cat *.txt to for writing output in send mail , but I need each file to be on a separate line.
What is the best way to mange files  appearing on a new line?

Comment: Could you add an example file and what command are you executing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in *.txt; do cat $i; echo; done | your_other_command
```